# How to save/load script with collapsed cells in SpyderIDE?

Tags: ide, editor, spyder

I made a huge spyder Script, with multiple cells with the #%% Seperator. Those may be collapsed and expanded on the left sidebar.

Is it possible to load a script with all cells collapsed? Now i need to collapse them all manually.

See this picture all but one cell is collapsed:

[image]

I seeked the internet for the problem and also looked into the IDE Preferences.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I'd also appreciate a similar functionality